# Adding objects to the DisplayList using variable

Tags: class, actionscript-3, object, movieclip, displaylist

Im trying to add objects to the displaylist, but for my project it would be good if i could run one piece of code that could place 1 of 5 objects onto the screen. Currently the code works if I put in the name of the object, but fails if I try to give it the class name through a variable. Any Ideas?

```
var sides:Array = new Array(Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge); 

var side1:sides[0] = new sides[0]();
centerHex.addChild(side1);
side1.y = side1.y - 20;
```

Throws this error:

1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftbracket.

This code works though:

```
var side1:Edge = new Edge();
centerHex.addChild(side1);
side1.y = side1.y - 20;
```

Any Ideas? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare variable as something from **Array**, because variable declaration is a compile-time operation, while **Array** items are available at runtime, which is **later**.

Also, you don't need to. Just declare it as **DisplayObject**, or don't declare at all, it is not mandatory, you are not obliged to, and it will be fine:

```
var Sides:Array = [Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge, Edge]; 

for (var i:int = 0; i < Sides.length; i++)
{
    var SideClass:Class = Sides[i];
    var aSide:DisplayObject = new SideClass;

    var anAngle:Number = i * Math.PI / 3;

    aSide.x = 100 * Math.cos(anAngle);
    aSide.y = 100 * Math.sin(anAngle);
    aSide.rotation = anAngle * 180 / Math.PI;

    centerHex.addChild(aSide);
}
```